# Java error during build hibernate-validator

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to build this project and getting this error with hibernate validator.  I am not referencing this class.   Doesn't look like an actual compile error.

This is the relevant hibernate validator reference.  Spring boot 1.5 application.

```
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Possible annotation not found?

Error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project priapp-mobileapi-proc: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/validator/group/DefaultGroupSequenceProvider: org.hibernate.validator.group.DefaultGroupSequenceProvider -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T14:49:05-05:00)
Maven home: /Users/user/Documents/tools/apache-maven-3.5.3
Java version: 1.8.0_301, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_301.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.7", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.group.DefaultGroupSequenceProvider
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:418)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:351)
at org.hibernate.validator.ap.checks.GroupSequenceProviderCheck. (GroupSequenceProviderCheck.java:63)
at org.hibernate.validator.ap.checks.ConstraintCheckFactory. (ConstraintCheckFactory.java:125)
at org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintAnnotationVisitor. (ConstraintAnnotationVisitor.java:68)
at org.hibernate.validator.ap.ConstraintValidationProcessor.process (ConstraintValidationProcessor.java:101)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:794)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:705)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800 (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing (JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations (JavaCompiler.java:1170)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile (JavaCompiler.java:856)
at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile (Main.java:523)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall (JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call (JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess (JavaxToolsCompiler.java:126)
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile (JavacCompiler.java:169)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:785)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:129)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)

Comment: I would recommend to read the docs https://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/ apart from using very old versions of Maven and JDK...

Comment: I fixed this by rearranging the order of certain dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked by changing the dependency order in the pom.xml